# How to disable file indexing in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have mounted ssh folders and i need to disable folder indexing because there is lots of files (images and other uploads). But even if i add

```
"files.exclude": {
    "**": true
}
```

i still see vscode running through all files and directories. Editor is running without extensions (removed all to check if they are providing some issues).
Although tried to use

```
"files.watcherExclude": {
    "**": true
},
```

but this didn't helped too when i open folder it start instantly indexing it.